# Testing Prism DialogService

Tags: unit-testing, prism

I have a Prism dialogService for confirmation (Yes and No buttons in dialog), and I use it this way;

```
bool confirmed = false;

DialogParameters p = new DialogParameters
{
    { "title", title },
    { "message", message }
};
dialogService.ShowDialog("ConfirmationDialog", p, r => { confirmed = r.Result == ButtonResult.OK; });

if (!confirmed)
{
    return;
}

// code I am not able to test
```

It works like a charm, but I am not able to test the code after the return, because "confirmed" is always false while I am executing tests, so it always returns and the code after the "return" is never executed.

I think the best way to test it should be to inject somehow the IDialogResult value in "r", so I can force that always I am testing `r.Result == ButtonResult.OK`. But... how can I do that?

Maybe my approach for confirmation dialog is not good, or maybe I am missing something, so any suggestion would be a great help for me.

Note: I use Fake It Easy for testing, but it is not a problem is the solution in explained in any other testing framework.

UPDATE: this is the implementation of the dialogService in the test:

```
dialogService = A.Fake<IDialogService>();
```

And then it is injected in the ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel(dialogService);
```

Thank you

Comment: It would help to see the implementation/creation of the `dialogService` in your test. If it's a mock, you could tell it to pass to the callback any arguments you desire...

Comment: @Haukinger, you are right, I have updated the question including how dialogService is implemented. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Fake It Easy, but with MOQ and NUnit, I'd write something like this:

```
// Arrange
var dialogServiceMock = new Mock<IDialogService>();
dialogServiceMock.Setup( x => x.ShowDialog( It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IDialogParameters>(), It.IsAny<Action<IDialogResult>>() ) )
                 .Callback<string, IDialogParameters, Action<IDialogResult>>( ( n, p, c ) => c( new DialogResult( ButtonResult.OK ) ) );

// Act
var receivedResult = ButtonResult.None;
dialogServiceMock.Object.ShowDialog( "my name", new DialogParameters( "my parameters" ), r => receivedResult = r.Result );

// Assert
Assert.That( receivedResult, Is.EqualTo( ButtonResult.OK ) );
```

Key point is the setup of the callback. Without it, the mock has no idea what to do with the `Action<IDialogResult>` parameter and even if it wanted to call it, it wouldn't know the parameters to use.

EDIT: Fake It Easy's equivalent to MOQ's `Callback` seems to be `Invokes` (found [here](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/invoking-custom-code/)).

Comment: Yesssssss, it is :) Maybe it is useful for someone, so Fake It Easy syntax is: A.CallTo(() => dialogService.ShowDialog(A<string>.Ignored, A<IDialogParameters>.Ignored, A<Action<IDialogResult>>.Ignored)).Invokes<string, IDialogParameters, Action<IDialogResult>>((n, p, c) => c(new DialogResult(ButtonResult.OK)));